# Extract complex roofshapes from LiDAR

Tags: arcgis-pro, lidar, 3d

I've been using the 3D Basemaps Solution on the ESRI Solutions page (I no longer see it listed) for a little over a year now with ArcGIS Pro with mixed but improving results to create scenery for use in a navigation simulator as it is faster then hand modelling.  My present workflow has me getting to the point of creating footprints and adding the roof attributes then bringing the footprints over to CityEngine where they can be linked up and pop out a city.

I have a bit of a hiccup though in the segmentation process.  In the Pre-process Building Footprints task, it allows you to segment the footprints analysing the DSM generated in a previous step and cutting footprints into smaller pieces for structures with a mixture of flat and sloped areas.

[image]

I was wondering how either I might control the spectral/spatial detail settings which do not seem to help much or if there's a better tool all together for doing this.